# Интеграция скрипта Python в приложение на Kotlin

Tags: java, python, android, kotlin, android-sdk

Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо встроить скрипт, написанный на `Python3` в приложение. Возможно ли это реализовать или стоит покопаться в аналогах на `Java`? Вообще были идеи поставить скрипт на сервер, но хочется реализацию на стороне клиента.

Comment: Что за скрипт, и как он должен быть связан с Java?

Comment: Можно принести вместе с проектом python и скрипт, запускать их и получать вывод. (через Runtime)

Comment: Скрипт написан на библиотеке `Telethon` для реализации `Telegram App`. Слабо понимаю. как принести проект на `Python`. Приведите пример, если можно.

Comment: В assets - держите скрипт и python для linux arm. При первом запуске расспакуйте все.А потом через Runtime, запустите скрипт и управляйте скриптом  через ввод/вывод. (для приложения в маркет - очень плохой подход)

Comment: Еще можно скачивать каждый раз при первом запуске, этот python. Он не мало весит

Comment: Найдите просто аналог для Java. 
https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi

Comment: Да, пожалуй использование аналога будет лучшем решением. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Отвечу для остальных прохожих.*

Можно при первом запуске приложения, скачивать python для linux arm и расспаковывать его в `/data/data/`...

Скрипт держать в приложении (`assets`, `raw`). Запускать скрипт через `Runnable`, и использовать ввод/вывод для общения со скриптом.

Этот способ очень плохой, не рекоменую.